# Turn on/off GPS programmatically without prompting the user in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm planning to code an application for the times when someone's iphone is lost or stolen. So it needs to tell the location of the phone via GPS, but in case it's stolen, it wouldn't be a good idea to ask the thief to turn on the GPS. So I'd like to know if there is a possibility of turning on/off the GPS without prompting the user. Thanks.

Comment: just to clarify - do you intend to distribute the app via App Store or Cydia?

Comment: You will likely need to have the user enable location services for the application first. And they would need to have restrictions set up to prevent the thief from disabling location services.

Comment: If such a way exists, there's a serious flaw in iOS. This would allow malicious software to control whether the phone's location is available or not, which is a serious risk to privacy and security. (Imagine someone's phone being told to locate them for someone who was planning an assault/murder/kidnapping, or a spouse tracking their husband/wife for some reason.)

Comment: @KenWhite Well i thought too that iOS wouldn't allow this. Well there is rooting for android and I _THINK_ when an application has root access it is able to go beyond restrictions such as this. I thought there might be something similar for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bypass the prompt completely. But it won't show up forever, if the user allows the app to use location data. Once the user allows this access twice, the app won't prompt any more. For an app like the one you describe, the user would have to do this first, and only then could future access proceed without a prompt.

There's still the pointer icon at the top of the screen when location services is active. There's no way around that, though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you have seen this or not: [Apple's 'find my iPhone'](http://www.apple.com/iphone/built-in-apps/find-my-iphone.html)

Either way, The app would have to be running, with GPS enabled, for the service to work correctly. Any half-wit thief would know to quit such an application